# PHP array group in loop and create multi dimensional associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have array named data as below

```
$data = array();
$data = array ( 
    [0] => Array (
                [class]         => 1styear 
                [branch]        => IT 
                [Exam]          => SEM1 
                [student name]  => Alex 
                [Bio]           => Good Boy
                 )
    [1] => Array ( 
                [class]         => 2ndyear 
                [branch]        => Finance 
                [Exam]          => SEM1 
                [student name]  => Mark
                [Bio]           => Intelligent 
                )
    [2] => Array (
                 [class]        => 2ndyear 
                 [branch]       => IT 
                 [Exam]         => SEM1 
                 [student name] => Shaun 
                 [Bio]          => Football Player
                  ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
                [class] => 1styear 
                [branch] => Finance 
                [Exam] => SEM2 
                [student name] => Mike 
                [Bio] => Sport Player 
                ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
                [class] => 1styear 
                [branch] => IT 
                [Exam] => SEM2 
                [student name] => Martin 
                [Bio] => Smart 
                 )
    [5] => Array ( 
                [class] => 1styear 
                [branch] => IT 
                [Exam] => SEM1 
                [student name] => Philip 
                [Bio] => Programmer
                  )
    )
```

class,branch ,exam can be repetitive
I need to group above elements and create nested multi dimensional associative array . array should look like this
 expected o/p

```
array(
    '1styear' =>
        array (
            0 =>
                array(
                    'Exam' => 'SEM1',
                    'branch' =>
                        array (
                            0 => 'IT'
                        ),
                ),
            1 =>
                array(
                    'Exam' => 'SEM2',
                    'branch' =>
                        array (
                            0 => 'IT'
                        ),
                ),
        ),
    '2ndyear' =>
        array (
            0 =>
                array(
                    'Exam' => 'SEM1',
                    'branch' =>
                        array (
                            0 => 'Finance',
                        ),
                ),
            1 =>
                array(
                    'Exam' => 'SEM2',
                    'branch' =>
                        array (
                            0 => 'Finance'
                        ),
                )
        ),
)
```

in  loop i tried following code

```
foreach($data as $array){
    $rr[$array["class"]]['Exam'][$array["Exam"]][] = array("Competitors" =>$array["Competitor"]) ;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the 2ndyear, sem1 contain 2 branches? IT & Finance in the multidim array example?

Key: 1 and 2 in your $data array.

Comment: Your input and desired output don't seem to match.

Comment: Show some idea about required array formate

Comment: @AndrewLarsen No I ment what I said. Output from a `var_export()` can easily become code that I can pop into a test. [See `var_export()` in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly but you wrote "var_dump", and var_dump would give you way more info, like datatype and length which is more then you want.

Comment: @AndrewLarsen Woops So I did, Silly me. I of course ment `var_export()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $res[$val['class']][] = ['Exam' => $val['Exam'],
                            'branch' => [$val['branch']]
      ]; 
}

print_r($res);
```

Comment: it doesn't return expected o/p. it should group by exam and then branch array